# Get Revenue Details in Google Sheets using Google Finance

Tags: sec, spreadsheet, google-finance

Recently I learned about GoogleFinance and it's feature to use Google Sheets to provide you with all stock market data using a formulae for eg.   `=GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "price", "1/1/2014", "12/31/2014", "DAILY")`

I read the doc that I found, however, I was not able to find any info if I can get the revenue of a particular stock using the same feature as well.

There should be something since, Google shows me the data on its tab when I check

[image]

How can I get this info in google sheet as well?

Comment: If you don't get answers here, you could try https://superuser.com or https://webapps.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4):

Use this formula in Google Sheets:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/finance/quote/TSLA:NASDAQ","//table//tr[contains(@class,'roXhBd')]")
```

This will bring up a list of the company's financial performance.

Comment: +1. That is a neat hack. It will work until Google Finance redesigns their quote pages.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) for the GOOGLEFINANCE API lists the attributes that are available depending on the type of security you're querying. None of them give you any detail about revenue - the closest is EPS (Earnings Per Share) which is *net* earnings, not just revenue.

You'll need to find another API or another data vendor to get revenue details.

Comment: It is interesting that in [this Google support answer](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308730?hl=en) it claims at the top that one of the things you can do with Google Finance is "See revenue trends and changes."  But I agree, there doesn't seem to be a way to actually do it.